# BBCode only use the first replacement but not the others

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, bbcode

The code below will only use the first line in the array (which makes the text bold).

```
function bbcode($string) {

    $codes = Array(
        '/\[b\](.+?)\[\/b\]/' => '<b>\1</b>',
        '/\[i\](.+?)\[\/i\]/' => '<i>\1</i>',
        '/\[u\](.+?)\[\/u\]/' => '<u>\1</u>',
        '/\[s\](.+?)\[\/s\]/' => '<s>\1</s>',
        '/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/' => '<a href="\1">\2</a>',
        '/\[image=(.+?)\]/' => '<div class="centered"><img src="\1" alt=""></div>'
    );

    while($replace = current($codes)) {
        $bbcode = preg_replace(key($codes), $replace, $string);
        next($codes);

        return stripslashes(nl2br($bbcode));
    }

}

echo bbcode('[b]This text[/b] will be bold and also [b]this text[/b]. But when I use some other BBCodes, it will [u]not[/u] work as planned. Here's a [url=http://google.com/]link[/url] too which will not be replaced as planned.');
```

Output: **This text** will be bold and also **this text**. But when I use some other bbcode, it will `[u]not[/u]` work as planned. Here's a `[url=http://google.com/]link[/url]` too which will not be replaced as planned.

How can I do so that my code will search for the right BBCode in the array and replace it with the key?

Comment: Sidenote: `preg_replace()` supports array parameters, you could nuke that whole loop. [Read the manual](http://php.net/preg-replace)

Comment: @HamZa: Thanks but what should `$replace` be instead? **EDIT** Nevermind! I figured it out :) `current($codes)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[preg_replace](https://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) accepts arrays as well for patterns and replacements.
Use the notation `$n` in the replacement part  instead of `\n` that is reserved for the pattern.

Here is what I'd do:

```
function bbcode($string) {
    $codes = Array(
        '/\[b\](.+?)\[\/b\]/' => '<b>$1</b>',
        '/\[i\](.+?)\[\/i\]/' => '<i>$1</i>',
        '/\[u\](.+?)\[\/u\]/' => '<u>$1</u>',
        '/\[s\](.+?)\[\/s\]/' => '<s>$1</s>',
        '/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/' => '<a href="$1">$2</a>',
        '/\[image=(.+?)\]/' => '<div class="centered"><img src="$1" alt=""></div>'
    );
    $bbcode = preg_replace(array_keys($codes), array_values($codes), $string);
    return stripslashes(nl2br($bbcode));
}
```